# how to solve "No ICP active "error in jade application?

Tags: agents-jade

i'm working on SMA  application with jade so when i run my maincontainer i got this error
SEVERE: Communication failure while joining agent platform: No ICP active
jade.core.IMTPException: No ICP active
solution pliz

Comment: can you attach full error stack. it looks like your port is already busy.

Comment: yes u'r % right  so i think i should  stop running my container each time before closing it  that was my solution for it